(Android) Bluetooth connection & Data transfer
Bluetooth Classic
Im new to bluetooth API's so please excuse my ignorance.
I managed to connect my Galaxy Buds using rfCommSocket via SPP UUID.
How i can now transfer commands to my device and receive data from it? I can't see any example code or docs regarding this. I know I need to construct it via inputStream and OutputStream but i can't see good examples for this. At least in android.
Not just galaxy buds but also other bluetooth devices for example. ex. Mouse/Printer/Etc
Any help/tips will do, I'm puzzled for days doing bluetooth there are so many inconsistencies & hidden methods.
Im following this docs : https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/bluetooth/setup

Does this answer your question? Bluetooth data transfer between two Android devices

Unfortunately no, since im trying to connect a non android device

Bluetooth has profiles or protocols for communication between supporting devices. A standard mouse would use Bluetooth HID, a printer has a different profile/protocol. Device specific customizations either is public or perhaps in a manufacturer SDK or requires reverse engineering for the specific device commands you are interested in.

See section 5.5.3 in the documentation here. It is not complete ready-to-run Android code, but it shows the key elements of setting up and reading/writing input and output RFCOMM streams. https://github.com/petzval/btferret

As Morrison Chang posted, you will not be able to communicate with the Galaxy buds using SPP as this profile is aimed for streaming data serially. For audio specific devices, you usually need to use Advanced Audio Distribution profile (A2DP) for streaming audio, and then use the Hands-Free Profile (HFP) or the Headset Profile (HSP) to control the device (e.g. take and make calls, adjust volume, etc).
You might find the links below useful:-

How to use HFP on Android programmatically
Bluetooth profile of paired device
Android Bluetooth profiles
Connecting to a Bluetooth A2DP device from Android

